# Replicating a Google ngram plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, nlp, n-gram

I'm trying to replicate a plot from the paper Michel et al., 'Quantitative Analysis of Culture Using Millions of Digitized Books' (2011). Specifically I'm trying to make the one on the top right here:
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/21163965/#&gid=article-figures&pid=fig-3-uid-2

I know the paper used v1 of the corpus but I'm doing it with v2 as it's easier to work with. When I use the Google Ngram viewer (specifying the English 2012 corpus which corresponds to v2, a year range of 1875 to 1975, and no smoothing) I get [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=1883%2C1910%2C1950&year_start=1875&year_end=1975&corpus=15&smoothing=0), which looks pretty close.

When I tried to replicate this in `R`/`ggplot` I get this:
[image]

1950 and 1883 look pretty consistent with what is happening in the viewer plot, but I can't figure out what is happening with 1910. There appears to be very few occurrences of the year '1910' in the data set in comparison to some of the other years. Would anyone with a better understanding of the Google ngrams data set be able to point me in the right direction? Should I be supplementing this with something other than just the 1-gram dataset? Does the Google ngram viewer pick out occurrences of 1-grams in a different way?

The code I've used is below. A couple of other points: 1910 and 1950 do not seem to exist as 1-grams in the v2 data set, but 1883 does. To get this to even remotely work, I had to `grepl` for 1950 and 1910 to get any hits (i.e. they all seem to appear as parts of date ranges like 1890-1910, or with some other characters tacked on), rather than just doing a fixed search for those years in the `ngram` field. I also used `purrr::map_dfr` to do this rather than just a `dplyr::case_when` in case years appeared in the same ngram picked up by a `grepl` (e.g. the range 1883-1910 should be a hit for both of those years, not just one).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

#---- Load data ----
counts_file <- file.path("data", "total_counts.txt")
ngrams_file <- file.path("data", "google_books_1gram_eng_v2.gz")

if (!dir.exists("data")) {
  dir.create("data")
}

if (!file.exists(counts_file)) {
  download.file(
    "http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/googlebooks-eng-all-totalcounts-20120701.txt",
    counts_file
  )
}
if (!file.exists(ngrams_file)) {
  download.file(
    "http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/googlebooks-eng-all-1gram-20120701-1.gz",
    ngrams_file
  )
}

one_grams <- read.delim(
  gzfile(ngrams_file),
  header = FALSE
)
names(one_grams) <- c("ngram", "year", "match_count", "volume_count")
one_grams_subset <- one_grams %>%
  filter(year >= 1875 & year <= 1975)

total_counts_temp <- t(
  read.table(
    counts_file, 
    header = FALSE
  )
)
total_counts_char <- do.call(
  rbind, 
  strsplit(total_counts_temp, ",")
)
total_counts <- apply(total_counts_char, 2, as.numeric)
colnames(total_counts) <- c("year", "match_count", "page_count", "volume_count")

#---- Recreate plot 3A from Michel et al. (2011) ----
year_subset <- function(year_char, one_grams_data) {
  one_grams_data %>% 
    filter(grepl(year_char, .[["ngram"]], fixed = TRUE)) %>% 
    group_by(year) %>% 
    summarise(year_count = sum(match_count, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
    mutate(year_gram = year_char)
}

plot_data <- map_dfr(c("1883", "1910", "1950"),
                     year_subset,
                     one_grams_subset) %>% 
  left_join(as_tibble(total_counts), by = "year") %>% 
  mutate(frequency = 10000 * year_count/match_count) %>% 
  select(year_gram, year, frequency, year_count)

ggplot(plot_data) +
  geom_line(aes(x = year, y = frequency, colour = year_gram)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(col = "ngram", x = "Year", y = "Frequency")
```

Comment: The shortage of 1910 entries in the ngram data makes me wonder if it is an error in the downloadable data (the data that the ngram viewer uses seems fine). If you look at the 'English 2020' version of the data, rather than 2012, the numbers look more sensible. As the paper you cite is from 2011, I guess the source was the 'English 2009' version, so it might be worth giving that a try. Otherwise your logic looks fine, although I'd be tempted to include some word boundaries (`\\b` or similar) in `grepl` (unless you want to include things like 10191037 as valid 1-grams).

Comment: The other thing is that you are just using the data file of 1-grams starting with a "1".  So you will miss examples such as "31-12-1910" or "pre-1910".  I think it is unlikely that this will make a huge difference, but it is perhaps worth bearing in mind.